# Having problem with very basic SilverLight LineSeries graph

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, .net-3.5, silverlight-4.0

I been stack for the last few days trying to figure out the SilverLight 4 LineSeries graph, for some strange reason the graph being displayed but the line not being displayed. I am pretty sure that my mistake is something very basic but I been straggling to pinpoint the problem by myself.

Bellow is the code that I having problem with.

```
<toolkit:Chart HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="chartLine" Margin="31,35,0,0" Title="Chart for test" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="233" Width="309">
        <toolkit:LineSeries IsSelectionEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" DependentValuePath="Y" IndependentValuePath="X" Margin="195,49,0,0" Name="lineSeries1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="78" Width="130">
                <toolkit:LineSeries.ItemsSource>          
                    <PointCollection>
                        <Point>1,10</Point>
                        <Point>2,20</Point>
                        <Point>3,30</Point>
                        <Point>4,40</Point>
                    </PointCollection>        
            </toolkit:LineSeries.ItemsSource>           

        </toolkit:LineSeries>           
        </toolkit:Chart>
```

I would also apreciate if anyone can point me to some code example with scrollable graph on Silverlight.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the corrected XAML.  Your problem is the HorizontalAlignment/VerticalAlignment/Margin/Width/Height you have set in the LineSeries.  Removing these fixes the problem.

Here's the complete XAML which shows the Chart with the lines properly placed.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <toolkit:Chart HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="chartLine" Margin="31,35,0,0" Title="Chart for test" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="233" Width="309">
      <toolkit:LineSeries IsSelectionEnabled="True" DependentValuePath="Y" IndependentValuePath="X" Name="lineSeries1">
        <toolkit:LineSeries.ItemsSource>
          <PointCollection>
            <Point>1,10</Point>
            <Point>2,20</Point>
            <Point>3,30</Point>
            <Point>4,40</Point>
          </PointCollection>
        </toolkit:LineSeries.ItemsSource>
      </toolkit:LineSeries>
    </toolkit:Chart>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I removed them tried again and it did not work, than took changed example that you provided it did not work again. It shows the chart but not the actual line inside the chart.

It is also appears that I cannot fully see X and Y panels. On the X I only see "0" and nothing on "Y".

Comment: @Dmitris it sounds like you have other issues with your XAML, possibly in the container immediately around your Chart, try providing a more complete sample code.  You could also try editing this bit of xaml in a new silverlight project in a blank page to see were the problem is.

Comment: @Dmitris I've updated my sample to show the complete XAML for a blank control with just the Chart on it.  See if that works for you.